# Using a dot product to get the least squares method

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a system of equations $Ax=b$ which has no solution so we look for an $\bar{x}$ such that  $A \bar{x} - b$ is minimal. This is minimal in the case that $A \bar{x} - b$ is an orthogonal projection of $b$ unto $A \bar{x}$.

In other words, this means that $(A \bar{x}-b) \cdot (A \bar{x}) = 0$. If possible, I want to use this result to get to the famous formula $A^T A \bar{x} = A^T b$, but I don't see how I can do this. Can anybody tell me how it's done, assuming it can be done? It seems to me that what I wrote is true, yet I don't see how my dot product can be related to the formula.

Comment: The dot product $x \cdot y = y^{T}x $. This should help.

Comment: @kolobokish Thanks, that did it for me, you should write that as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear algebra least squares - explanation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005592/linear-algebra-least-squares-explanation)

Comment: It was just a hint.))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dot product $\langle x \cdot y\rangle$ is the usual, the formula to calculate it is the same as calculating the product $y^Tx$. Using that we can show what you want:

$$\langle(A\bar{x} - b)\cdot(A\bar{x})\rangle = 0 \iff \langle A\bar{x}\cdot A\bar{x}\rangle - \langle b \cdot A\bar{x}\rangle = 0 \iff$$

$$\iff (A\bar{x})^T(A\bar{x}) - (A\bar{x})^Tb = 0 \iff \bar{x}^TA^TA\bar{x} - \bar{x}^TA^Tb = 0 \iff$$

$$\iff \bar{x}^TA^TA\bar{x} = \bar{x}^TA^Tb \iff A^TA\bar{x} = A^Tb$$